# Selenium 3 Grid in Java: SessionNotCreatedException for Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Using Selenium 3 I am not able to run tests in my grid using Chrome. Here's my setup:

```java
@Before
public void setUp() {

    this.baseUrl = Config.getProperty("WEBAPP.PATH");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities chromeCaps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    chromeCaps.setVersion("54.0.2840.99");
    this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(SELENIUM_GRID_URL), chromeCaps);

}
```

Here's my node's config:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
      "browser-version": "54.0.2840.99"
    },
    {
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444"
}
```

But the exception when calling the `RemoteWebDriver` constructor is always:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=54.0.2840.99, platform=WIN10}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-G3JOA4U', ip: '192.168.212.50', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at de.myproject.SeleniumTest.setUp(SeleniumTest.java:71)
```

I also tried altering the node config like this:

`"webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"`

Always the same error...

Versions:

```
selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
selenium-java-3.0.1.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.0.1.jar
selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar
selenium-api-3.0.1.jar
jdk1.8.0_112
```

Grid running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Open a command prompt and enter "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"    What version of chrome do you have installed?

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.25.426923

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.25 should work with chrome browser 54.0. Check the path environment variable and make sure that ChromeDriver 2.25 is in the path and that no previous version of ChromeDriver is in the path.